# Simulating latency to a URL using ipfw

Tags: networking, latency, ipfw

How can I simulate latency to a single URL?

I tried following to simulate latency to a single URL by adding a ipfw rule.

```
sudo ipfw add pipe 1 ip  from  myurl.com to any
#(response of running above command) 00100 pipe 1 ip from any to any
sudo ipfw add pipe 1 ip  from  any to myurl.com
#(response of running above command) 00200 pipe 2 ip from any to any


sudo   ipfw pipe 1 config delay 10000ms bw 1Kbit/s
sudo   ipfw pipe 2 config delay 10000ms bw 1Kbit/s
```

However, above rules introduce to *all* URLs, and not just myurl.com

Am I missing something to introduce latency to just myurl.com

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
# latency.sh    

oif="em0" # just the interface looking to the outer space

# let's create two seperate pipes
ipfw pipe 1 config delay 10000ms bw 1Kbit/s
ipfw pipe 2 config delay 10000ms bw 1Kbit/s

# let's pipe some traffic
# going in...
ipfw add 1000 pipe 1 all from myurl.com to any in via $oif
# and out...
ipfw add 1001 pipe 2 all from any to myurl.com out via $oif
# that's all
```

# sudo ./latency.sh